# How to find if the VB string variable has the vbTab and replace with underscores or some other characters

Tags: vb.net

How to find whether the given VB.Net string has the vbCrLf, vbTab and other built in constants then replace them with some other characters like underscore or hyphen etc. I am stuck on the below code for some time and could not get to figure out why it is not replaced.

```
       Dim msg As String
       msg = "Hello I am test message" & vbTab & vbTab & " After two tabs " & vbCrLf & "I am in next line"
       msg = msg.Replace("vbTab", "____")
       msg = msg.Replace("&vbTab&", "****")
       MessageBox.Show(msg)
```

OUTPUT: I get tab instead of  underscore or asterich.

[image]

Comment: What about `Dim Replaced As String = MyStringVariable.Replace(vbTab, "_")`?

Comment: vbCrLf and vbTab aren't functions. Technically, they're constants that represent control codes (vbTab is defined as the tab control-character, vbCrLf is Carriage Return + Line Feed.)

Comment: Loads of examples of how to do this. Google is your friend.

Comment: @Waescher That will not replace the vbTab or vbCrLf

Comment: @Bugs no examples in google

Comment: [Maybe you are doing it wrong](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mOXtrN) because Replace does work

Comment: without code being shown, I'll say wild guess is that you're calling the replace function without actually assigning the replaced value to a string.`Replace (vbTab, "_")` by itself doesn't do anything.  This is a wild guess, however, given the lack of code being shown.

Comment: @eham first: ofc - this does just replace vbTab, you have to think a bit for yourself and second: no results on google? must be the first thing ever on the internet ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to replace a literal string of 5 characters "vbTab" rather than the Tab character.

Remove the quotes around vbTab in your Replace function and you will get the underscores in your output

```
 Dim msg As String
 msg = "Hello I am test message" & vbTab & vbTab & " After two tabs " & vbCrLf & "I am in next line"
 msg = msg.Replace(vbTab, "____")
 ''msg = msg.Replace("&vbTab&", "****")  No idea how to fix this as it will never match anything
 MessageBox.Show(msg)
```

I don't know what you're trying to achieve with your second Replace as this seems to be trying to replace a tab character surrounded by two concatenation operators. The concatenation operators will never be in the string, and after the first Replace is executed, there wouldn't be any vbTabs remaining anyway.